# Does RIP stores information about entire AS?

Tags: routing, rip

I am studying routing protocols for one of the certification exam, and confused with the following question:

1. Does **RIP V2** (Distance Vector protocol) store the distance vector table for every possible destination(networks) within a given AS. Here I mean like any given router on the AS knows all the network hops required to reach the destination computer/server, something like what 'trace route' command gives.

or

2. only stores what its neighbour routers know?. Here I mean like any give router on the AS has only a partial answer to reach the destination computer/server.

Any help to throw light on this is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions or help about examinations are off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

RIP is an **Interior Gateway Protocol**, it means that it was designed to operate within a single *autonomous system* (AS).

RIP version 2 was developed as a fix of deficiencies on RIPv1  mainly in the ability of supporting CIDR.

To maintain backward compatibility, the original *hop count limit of 15* remained, it means that if a router receives a RIP message indicating a subnet 16 hops farther, that information will be dismissed and the consequence will be that the routing table in that router won't show every destination available.

Answer (score 2):

Being a distance vector protocol means it only learns and advertises prefixes with it's direct neighbors.  It has no "full" view of the network topology.